# MongoDb how to get a list of unique fields from a pojo doc

Tags: java, mongodb, distinct

I'm new to Mongodb and I'm trying to get what I thought would be quite a simple unique call on a field. What I want is a list of all the unique or distinct (one of each) marketIds:

```
sample doc -> added to local mongodb as a pojo (with a double array codec)
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63fe576c931a3f5dc2aa355d"
    },
    "con": false,
    "img": true,
    "marketId": "MSFT134048",
    "totalMatched": 525.9,
    "tsMs": {
      "$numberLong": "1677612908236"
    }
    ...
  }
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63fe576c931a3f5dc2aa355e"
    },
    "con": false,
    "img": true,
    "marketId": "MSFT134050",
    "totalMatched": 529.5,
    "tsMs": {
      "$numberLong": "1677612908236"
    }
    ...
  }
```

I'd like either two full documents or a set of the two marketIds (both containing [MSFT134048, MSFT134050] the latter is preferable).

I'm using the local desktop version of mongodb (not paid-for Atlas).

The various methods I've tried either get an error or empty results:

1. `var doc = quoteCol.distinct("marketId", PriceUpdate.class);`
2. `var doc = quoteCol.distinct("marketId", Document.class);`

```
error: CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING
```

3. So, maybe not distinct, how about aggregate:

   ```
   final Bson field1 = new Document("marketId", "$marketId");
   final List<Bson> bsonList = Arrays.asList(field1);
   var ret = quoteCol.aggregate(bsonList);
   Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'marketId'
   ```
4. Agreggate with group:

   ```
   final Bson field1 = new Document("marketId", "$marketId");`
   final Bson groupField = new Document("_id", field1);`
   final Bson group = new Document("$group", groupField);`
   final List<Bson> bsonList = Arrays.asList(group);`
   var ret = quoteCol.aggregate(bsonList);`
   The return from the above is a list of unpopulated docs with null marketIds.
   ```

How to do it please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> So, maybe not distinct

The error message suggests that the `distinct` method is not able to return the expected result because the `marketId` field is not of type `String`, which is what the method expects by default.

You can still use the `distinct` method as follows:

```
List<String> marketIds = quoteCol
    .distinct("marketId", String.class)
    .into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: The suggestion is good - thanks

Comment: https://github.com/vincentrussell/sql-to-mongo-db-query-converter